# Latin small letter a with diaeresis (ä) invalid in xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I think this is only a globalization issue or a matter where I should replace this small letter a with diaeresis in the correct encoding, but for now I am not sure how.

I have recently started learning VB.NET and it would seem that string escaping is not supported. As a little practice application against live data, I wrote the following:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(GetXml().Substring(800, 50))
    Transform()
End Sub

Sub Transform()
    Dim xml = GetXml()
    Dim xsl = GetXsl()
    Dim writer As New StringWriter()
    Dim xPath = New XPathDocument(GetReader(xml))
    Dim xslTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
    xslTransform.Load(GetReader(xsl))
    xslTransform.Transform(xPath, Nothing, writer)

    Console.Write(writer.ToString())
End Sub

Public Function GetReader(input As String) As XmlReader
    Dim memStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input)
    memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    memStream.Position = 0
    Return XmlReader.Create(memStream)
End Function
```

`GetXml` and `GetXsl` literally returns a hardcoded xml string and a hardcoded xsl string. the problem is that the data was procured from one of our live system and is German. I will get similar data to work with in the future. This means that I encountered the character in the title, and also go the following error in runtime:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given enc
oding. Line 1, position 804.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32&
 charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type, Int32&
outStartPos, Int32& outEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace s
pace)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader)
   at VBXSLTtoXML.Module1.Transform() in c:\users\eon\documents\visual studio 20
13\Projects\VBXSLTtoXML\VBXSLTtoXML\Module1.vb:line 18
   at VBXSLTtoXML.Module1.Main() in c:\users\eon\documents\visual studio 2013\Pr
ojects\VBXSLTtoXML\VBXSLTtoXML\Module1.vb:line 11
```

For now, what can I do to resolve the error and allow the New XPathDocument(GetReader(xml)) pass? Should I modify the retrieved XML to replace non-supported characters ?

Comment: `Invalid character in the given encoding.` What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: It's a hardcoded string. that's it. 

`Public Function GetXml() As String Return "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &` ...

Comment: it's around 1000 lines, can't copy paste that all :)

Comment: So the XML says UTF-8, but is the file actually read as UTF-8? My guess is that there's a conflict of encoding here. Either the file is in the wrong encoding, or the program tries to read it in the wrong encoding. Can you specify the encoding explicitly when reading in the XML?

Comment: I think you got it. GetReader function - `Encoding.*Default*.GetBytes()`

I missed that. pop your answer down . will mark it

Comment: This code got past the stuck point and failed elsewhere. I can take it from here. Thanks @jurgemaister

Comment: Glad you resolved it. Character encodings can be a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with character encoding, it's always a good idea to explicitly tell the parser what encoding to use.

You would believe that since the XML states `<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>` the encoder would automatically pick UTF-8, but sadly this isn't always the case.

As stated in your own reply to yourself above, use the GetReader function - `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.